# DollarFormat with minus sign in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, number-formatting

I'm trying to get a value of -1000 to be formatted at -$1,000.00 in ColdFusion.
When using dollarFormat it displays negative numbers in parenthesis like ($1,000.00).
when I use numberFormat like so:

```
numberFormat(-1000,'$');
```

It displays as -$1000 without the 2 decimal places and comma but displays the minus sign in the correct position.
If I try:

```
numberFormat(-1000,'$_,___.__');
```

It displays as $-1,000.00 where the minus sign is after the $ sign.
If I try:

```
numberFormat(-1000,'-$_,___.__');
```

It still displays as $-1,000.00 where the minus sign is after the $ sign.

Seems like if there is no decimal then the minus sign is in the correct position but as soon as you add a decimal then the minus sign comes after the dollar sign.
Does anyone know how to get it for format correctly like -$1,000.00?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Java's [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), which allows one to provide a formatting mask for both positive and negative numbers:

```
for (v in [1234,-5678]){
    result = createObject("java", "java.text.DecimalFormat").init("$##,####0.00;-$##,####0.00").format(javacast("double",v));
    writeDump(var=[v, result]);
    writeOutput("<hr>");
}
```

Obviously wrap that in a UDF.

Comment: much better answer than mine

Comment: Heh. I found most of it... on Stack Overflow ;-)

Comment: It is a shame that `dollarFormat()` does not have a way to customize the output. Doing `dollarFormat(-18)` returns `($18.00)`. So, it kind of takes care of it..just not in a way that some people would want.

Comment: @ScottStroz I can think of no reason someone should not raise an enhancement request to get a second optional argument added to `dollarFormat()` so as to deal with this more flexibly. Or deprecate all of `dollarFormat()`, `LSCurrencyFormat()`, `LSEuroCurrencyFormat()` in favour of one unified `currencyFormat()` which is both locale-aware and maskable. There is no way in the 21stC that there's a need for NON-locale-aware functions. So no need to have ones prefixed with LS or specify currency names in their name. It's archaic language design.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to write your own function.  Why not simply note if the value is less than zero (negative) and then take its absolute value `abs(-1000)` then dollar format that and if it was negative, prepend the `-`.

something like this (untested):

```
<cfscript>
public string function myCurrencyFormatter(num) {
  var neg = (num < 0);
  var str = dollarFormat(abs(num));
  if (neg) {
    str = "-" & str;
  }
  return str;
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that as well but wondered if there's some special formatting condition I apply in numberFormat() to make it work, but I guess there isn't

Comment: Tested and it works. Prefer this to creating an object for each request. Especially if you've got tons of numbers to format on a request.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numberFormat(n, "$.00")` to output as `-$9.00` for `n=9`.